# How do I open a query window using the IRC URI scheme?

Tags: uri, irc

Generally, the IRC URI scheme URLs are like this to join a channel:

```
irc://irc.example.com/channel
```

You would think the `channel` should have a hash (`#`) in front of it to denote it's a channel and cause your client to join it, while without the hash it would just open a query window with the nick `channel`.

However, it seems that without a hash it'll just join the channel, and adding a hash it'll just join `##channel` instead.

I've searched around quite a bit and I'm unable to find a method of querying users with the URI scheme.

Does anyone here know how this could be possible?

Answer (score 1):

There's a draft for the IRC URL scheme here: http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/draft-mirashi-url-irc-01.txt

It's not guaranteed that all clients or resource locators will adhere to the draft, but according to the document, you want something that looks like this:

```
irc://foobar.org/Mmmm,isnick
```

where `Mmmm` is the nick. The key is that you need the `,isnick` string in the target otherwise the URL will be treated as a channel. Additionally, you can include the ident info in the URL as well:

```
irc://foobar.org/Mmmm!mandar@*uoknor.edu,isnick
```